# tf.saved_model.save throwing 'ValueError: None values not supported'

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror

I'm trying to train an SSD neural net with python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.14
Here is the code, which is mostly copied from https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_image_retraining

```
import itertools
import os

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

print("TF version:", tf.__version__)
print("Hub version:", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")

module_selection = ("mobilenet_v2_100_224", 224) 
handle_base, pixels = module_selection
MODULE_HANDLE ="https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/{}/feature_vector/4".format(handle_base)
IMAGE_SIZE = (pixels, pixels)
print("Using {} with input size {}".format(MODULE_HANDLE, IMAGE_SIZE))

BATCH_SIZE = 32


data_dir = 'flower_photos'

datagen_kwargs = dict(rescale=1./255, validation_split=.20)
dataflow_kwargs = dict(target_size=IMAGE_SIZE, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                   interpolation="bilinear")

valid_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    **datagen_kwargs)
valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir, subset="validation", shuffle=False, **dataflow_kwargs)

do_data_augmentation = False 
if do_data_augmentation:
  train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
      rotation_range=40,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
      **datagen_kwargs)
else:
  train_datagen = valid_datagen
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir, subset="training", shuffle=True, **dataflow_kwargs)



do_fine_tuning = False 

print("Building model with", MODULE_HANDLE)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Explicitly define the input shape so the model can be properly
    # loaded by the TFLiteConverter
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + (3,)),
    hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE, trainable=do_fine_tuning),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes,
                          kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])
model.build((None,)+IMAGE_SIZE+(3,))
model.summary()

model.compile(
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.005, momentum=0.9), 
  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, label_smoothing=0.1),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size
validation_steps = valid_generator.samples // valid_generator.batch_size
hist = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_steps).history

saved_model_path = "saved_flowers_model"
tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_path)
```

every time it gets to the last line it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Threat_Assesser\retrain.py", line 78, in <module>
    tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_path)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py", line 822, in save
    meta_graph_def, saveable_view, signatures)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py", line 510, in _fill_meta_graph_def
    object_map, resource_map, asset_info = saveable_view.map_resources()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py", line 245, in map_resources
    tensor_util.constant_value(capture))
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 246, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 284, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 454, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Anyone know what's going on here?